# How could I access the ring and vibration as an alert from java script or html

Tags: javascript, iphone

How could I access the ring and vibration as an alert from java script or html.

I am trying to activate the ring tone, when AJAX returns the valid data.

I couldn't find anything so far.

Thanks,
Zafer Boz

Answer (score 0):

You can't access vibration or alert through javascript. You could play your own sound though through HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why you can't output CTLg